# Downloading different img formats in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to download an image to an Android phone.  The issue is the image is delivered via a generic HttpHandler and will deliver different images in different formats.  The requests all go to a `http://.../MyImage.ashx` url.  Using PhoneGaps FileTransfer, is it possible to determine the file extension of the image?  I am using PhoneGap 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

If you by "file extension" mean the file suffix, like .png, .jpg and so on, this may be done extracting the last part of the filename like e.g. this:

```
var filename = 'someimage.png';
var extension = '';
var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
if(lastIndex > -1) {
  extension = filename.substr(lastIndex + 1);
}
```

In this example extension will be 'png'. Another way to go is to get the mimetype of the file using Phponegap's File API. When using the download function, you get a FileEntry object. This has a file() function which gives you access to file properties. One of these properties is 'type', which is the mimetype (e.q 'image/png'). This is documented here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html